# Line-height was larger than paragraph

Tags: css, html

I set font to 200px and line height to 200px, when i set it I expected font height exactly 200px but it isnt :(, paragraf has height 200px, but font has 223px, can you tell my why?

HTML

```
<p class="par">
A<span id="why">Áj</span>gxÁj
</p>
```

CSS

```
body{font-size: 200px;font-family: Arial;line-height: 200px;}
.par{background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);}
#why{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0466uLkv/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Your font size is `200px` itself `223px` is `height` of `span`.

You can check this in inspect element.

Use `F12`, or `Ctrl+Shift+I` to open the Developer Tools in chrome.

[image]

Comment: Yes, span has 223, but font with glyps has 223 too, but i want font with ascender and descender exactly 200px, it posible?

Answer (score 0):

An inline element may be taller than the font-size since some glyphs extend beyond the bounding box, and inline elements can wrap. You can make a `<span>` height match the font size by giving it `display: inline-block`. For line-height, I prefer to use unitless: `line-height: 1`

Comment: I want to paragraph have exactly the same height as the font with glyphs. I do not mean span, only about the size paragraph.

Comment: You can use span instead of p so that the height matches. You might need to provide more context for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would just get the answer why font with glyps is taller than p? When i use span instead p, i get height 223, but i want exactly 200px, it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Setting the font-size to 200px means that characters will generally be 200px tall with some exceptions like Á. Every font is a little different. If you are going for pixel perfect design, use a line-height greater than 1 to contain the text.

Comment: Ok i understand this, but font without glyps arn't 200px, element p has exactly 200px and is taller than example normal "A", why? Whad does mean font height 200px?

Comment: ok, i see you dont know too;, mayby you read this:
http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/line-height
slide nr. 73 becouse i dont find the answer :(